# Monzo, automatically transfer on url trigger

Tags: webhooks, onlinebanking

I’m a novice so any help would be greatly appreciated.
I want to be able to automatically transfer a set amount, each time a URL is triggered.
The idea would be, I would set a iOS shortcut, with the ‘get contents of url’ and each time £5 would be transferred to a pre-determined account.
Is this possible?

I’ve searched and seen that Monzo has webhooks, is this a way of doing it?